# How do I square a predefined array and print it in 3 integer spaces

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I need to square the predefined array, but the problem is the iteration depends on what number the user enter is. I'm only new to java and do not know how it works.

```java
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // Predefined array.

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

int num = in.nextInt(); // Number of loop.
int sq = 0, sq2 = 0, sq3 = 0, sq4 = 0, sq5 = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    sq = array[i] * array[i];
    sq2 = array[i] * array[i];
    sq3 = array[i] * array[i];
    sq4 = array[i] * array[i];
    sq5 = array[i] * array[i];
}

for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    System.out.println(sq);
    System.out.println(sq2);
    System.out.println(sq3);
    System.out.println(sq4);
    System.out.println(sq5);
}
```

***Input:***

```
1 //iteration
```

***Output:***

```
1
1
1
1
1
```

***Expected output:***

```
001
004
009
016
025
```

Comment: "the iteration depends on what number the user enter is." <- How does it depend and how did you try to implement it? This doesn't make sense to me and the way you coded it in as a restriction doesn't really help me understand what this user entered number is supposed to represent and do.

Comment: if the user enter 1 then the loop would only loop once and square the number inside the array. @OH GOD SPIDERS

Answer (score 3):

The value of `i` is 0 in the beginning. So all the values are actually storing the square of the 0th element that is the first element in the array which means they are all storing the square of "1".
Your code should be somewhat like this:

```
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; // Predefined array.
    
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
      
int num = in.nextInt(); // Number of loop.
int[] sq = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
  
for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        sq[j] = array[j] * array[j];
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  System.out.println(sq[i]);
}
```

This should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

to find the square of a number you can also use `Math.pow()`,

1. the `num` which it's value will be entered by user may cause problem so you need also to check that the value of `i` which is the index of array do not exceed from the arrays index
2. you need to use a `printf` to format the number output with leading zero:

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }; // Predefined array.

Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

int num = in.nextInt(); // Number of loop.
for (int i = 0; i < num && i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.printf("%03d\n", array[i] * array[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use *streams* to square the elements of an array:

```java
int[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

```java
// number of iterations
int i = 1;
// multiply each element of the array 'i' times
int[] squared = Arrays.stream(array)
        .map(j -> IntStream.rangeClosed(0, i)
                .map(k -> j)
                .reduce(Math::multiplyExact)
                .orElse(j))
        .toArray();
```

```java
// output
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(squared));
// [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
```

---

<sup>See also: [Returning a 2d array from inputed 1d array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66787036/15402945)</sup>